# SQL database data into webpage using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hi I have a very large dataset with 300,000 rows that I need to somehow insert into the webpage, unfortunately the webpage takes a long time to load with all of that information, is there a way using Django and python, that I can throw the data into some kind of list and then show it page by page? Thanks.

Comment: The term you're looking for is *pagination*...

Comment: Take a look at Datatable https://datatables.net/ in it's server-side processing mode. There is also django-datatable .